# VB6.0 with DataControl Database Programming

Tags: vb6

Hey, can I ask you something? I'm using VB6.0 and I have some problem with the connection of my Database through ***DataControl***. I have a table named ***tblEmployee*** and the other one is ***tblPosition*** then I passed the value of the two tables to two ***DataControls*** respectively. How can I then get the value of a certain row of ***Position*** field. With my code, my ***Position*** field returns only the first row. Here's my code

```
Private Sub cmdSearchEmployee_Click()
With datEmployee.Recordset
    datEmployee.Recordset.Index = "idxid"
    datEmployee.Recordset.Seek "=", txtIDNumber.Text

    If .NoMatch = True Then
        MsgBox ("No Record Found!")
    Else
        Me.txtLastName.Text = .Fields("lname")
        Me.txtFirstName.Text = .Fields("fname")
        Me.txtMiddleName.Text = .Fields("mi")

        With datPosition.Recordset
            Me.txtPosition.Text = .Fields("position")

        End With
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see that you have "passed the value" to your DataControl named `datPosition`. Could this be the problem? e.g. where you have

```
    With datPosition.Recordset
        Me.txtPosition.Text = .Fields("position")

    End With
```

...should be more like this:

```
    With datPosition.Recordset
        .Index = "some_index??"
        .Seek "=", "some_value??"
        Me.txtPosition.Text = .Fields("position")
    End With
```

Also consider using the recordsets' `Filter` to remove the rows that do not match your criteria then `RecordCount` to loop through the rows that do match your criteria.

Further consider returning a single recordset by creating a join between `tblEmployee` and `tblPosition`, either in SQL code or returning a hierarchical recordset using the MsDataShape with its [SHAPE](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;189657) syntax.

Comment: Yes I set the Properties of the two DataControls [DatabaseName, RecordSetType, and RecordSource]. How can I do that, the _**tblEmployee**_ has an index of idxEmployee and the _**tblPosition**_ has idxPosition. Please give me some syntax.

Comment: The program should first look for the ID Number and when the ID Number exists, further information[lname,fname,mi,position] should appear n Textboxes respectively.